# how to know the full path of new created file?

Tags: c, linux, path, fopen

see i have make one program which create one new file just using

```
fopen()
```

Now i want to print full path of that file's in ma program.

How is that possible in `linux` with c programming?

Comment: The Path where the file gets created is a concern to OS not the programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard C by itself provides no way to do this, actually. But the POSIX standard has [getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd). What you would do is append the path used to create the file to the working directory path obtained from `getcwd` -- unless, of course, the path used to create the file is an absolute path.

Alternatively, you could use [realpath](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath).

Answer (score 0):

You already have a file name, so the question is more how to detect whether it's already an absolute path or a relative path and turn the latter into an absolute path.

If it's an absolute path already, then the string will start with a `/`.  If it's not an absolute path, then you know it's relative to your current working directory.  Given that, you can determine the current working directory of your process and append the file path to that.

If you also want to resolve it to a real path (resolve symlinks, remove `.` and `..` portions) you can use the realpath function.

Answer (score -3):

In *main()* you should get the full path of your executable as *argv[0]*. Your file is created there.

Also, AFAIK, fopen prototype is

```
FILE * fopen(const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode);
```

So a plain

```
fopen()
```

would not work (if we're talking about standard C).

Comment: No; you're not guaranteed that argv[0] contains the full path, and there's absolutely no guarantee, or even an expectation, that the current working directory is where the executable is.